# Where to we implement AbstractControl in angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2, abstract-class

I have written a code , I do no where to write the **AbstractControl**

here is the code

```
 @Component({
     selector: 'page-sinup',
     templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })

 export const Validate = (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
  const firstname    = control.get('firstname');
  const useridphone  = control.get('useridphone');
  const password     = control.get('password');
  const email        = control.get('email');
  };
  export class SinupPage {
  }
```

i have written the Abstract Control in first  class, its showing error
{ [key: string]: any } => {}
firstname is undefined all the fields are showing error, I do no where to erite a code, for displaying error messageswhen it is build in the ionic2 app

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What is the expected and the actual behavior? Why do you think you need to use `AbstractControl`?

Comment: when i build the ionic app in android, shows error **AbstractControl  { [key: string]: any } ** thats why i want use abstract control in app , for displaying error messages in builded app